# Oracale Paramerters different for IIS Application Pool

Tags: oracle, web-services, iis, web-applications, application-pool

I have an oracle database in korean language for which two applications connect one is a web application configured with an application pool of 4.0 Classic were the other one is an application of web services that it is configured with an application pool 4.0 Integrated.

There is a stored procedure that contains the following code 
TO_CHAR(stringDateValue,'mm/dd/yyyy')

Both client applications are located in an environment that is configured with an american language.

When the web application calls the procedure the value stored in the database it is formatted in english as expected but when the web services applications calls the procedure it stored the value formatted in korean.

1. Is there any difference when using integrated vs classic application pools for when the database is in another language other than english?
2. why are the dates beign formatted different for both applications that are calling the same procedure?
3. What other information is needed or required for further evaluation?